# Animation in Android's WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, flash, gif

As far as I know, swf's and gif's inside WebViews are not officially supported by Android, eventhough they work in my HTC Desire Device.

I'm building an app that it's all based in a WebView. What i did is code the 'app' as HTML, put it into the 'raw' folder and once the app starts, it puts all the htmls and images into a folder on the SD (if they're not there yet).

Now I need display some animations in there. I made them with Actionscript and I was glad that it seemed to work (Animations were 25KB each), but after a while publishing it, i got reports from people that coulnd't see the animation.

Then I patched them into a GIF (raised memory to 400KB-1MB each). At this point, I decided to take the gifs out of the raw folder, and download them from one server in the web the first time the app runs, so my apk doesn't get too big. But I get complaints again that people can't see it (then I found that GIF is also unsupported)

Google-ing and stackoverflow-ing I found that the only solution is to split those GIFs into separate images and show them with javascript one by one to create the animation. I guess this method is OK for small animations (like some face saying hello or something like that), but for whole animations.... It weights about 3MB per animation (when the swf was 25KB...). And I think taking 30MB (possibly more in the future for new animations) from user's data quota is not nice.

So:

1. Is there any other solution?
2. Are there lots and lots of phones that don't support SWF? and GIF? If they're not too many, I would consider putting on my app's description that the animations won't work if the phone has low memory (animations are not very important into my app)

Thank you very much,

Víctor

edit: Additional information: Animations are like [this one](http://livewind.olisrv.org/rrv_downloads/rule13a.gif).

Comment: "Are there lots and lots of phones that don't support SWF?" -- since Flash on Android is no longer offered by Adobe, eventually 100% of phones will not support SWF.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. Then SWF is discarted. And what about using HTML5? Browsing arround the web I see most smartphones do support it... and since the animation is not too big I don't think it will be a huge issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I found the only way was to use HTML5 canvas animation, since surprisingly it is supported  by many devices.

The animation is not as smooth as in a GIF-compatible device, but I rather make it accessible for everyone.

So, CommonsWare answered my 2nd question, but I will answer my 1st one: Yes, use HTML5. It didn't take a huge work, since JS can be Object-Oriented as well, and syntax is fairly similar to AS3.

And the best part is that the base code only weights 34KB (let's say the engine plus all the images), and each animation (in a separate file) weights between 1 and 2KB. That was awesome, I can put them all into my Android's raw folder.

Thank you very much CommonsWare for your comment.